# Show that $\lim _n (X \setminus E _n ) =(X \setminus \lim _n E _n )$, for $E_n $ an increasing sequence of sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{E _n \} $ be a sequence of subsets of $X $ defnined as $E _n=\cap _{m=n } ^{\infty } A _m $, so that $E _n \subset E _{n+1 }\subset ...$ .

Let $E = \lim E _n = \cup _{n=1 } ^{\infty } E _n$

I want to show that $\lim _{n \to \infty } (X \setminus E _n ) =(X \setminus E )$

(Actually I want to show that $\lim _{n \to \infty } \mu (X \setminus E _n )= \mu (X \setminus E) $, but I know that I can take the limit inside the measure since the sequence is monotone)

---

We have that $X \setminus E _n \supset X \setminus E _{n+1 }\supset ...$, so that $\lim _{n \to \infty } (X \setminus E _n ) = \cap _{n=1 } ^{\infty } (X \setminus E  ) $

if $x \in \cap _{n=1 } ^{\infty } (X \setminus E _n ) \iff \forall n \ge (x \in X \wedge x \notin E _n)$ is this equivalent to $x \in X \wedge (\forall n \ge 1: x \notin E _n ) $?

*I think the quantifier makes me unsure of what is correct here...*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Defnined as $E _n=\cap _{m=n } ^{\infty } A _m $", but you never said what $A_m$ is.

Comment: Maybe I could use de Morgans law?

Comment: Ok, $A _n = \{x: |f _m (x)- f(x) |< 1/k \} $ where $\{f _n \} $ is a sequence of measurable functions that converges a.e. to $f $

Comment: Actually I should have written $A _n ^k $, and the limit is taken with respect to $n $.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635042/sequences-of-sets-property) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999066/troubles-proving-bigcup-n-in-mathbb-na-n-bigcup-n-in-mathbb-n-bigla-n?lq=1).

Comment: Could you give me a hint how I should use this result?

Comment: Ignore the links, I thought the techniques might be useful, but I see now that you're close to the solution. Yes, $x\in \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(X\setminus E_n\right)\iff x\in X\land \forall n\in \mathbb N(x\not \in E_n)$.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: OK, do you understand the equivalence above?

Comment: No, it's a typo. I'll write out an answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Let me know if there's something you don't understand. For now I suggest we delete the comments up until 'Could you give me a hint how I should use this result?' because they are now unnecessary. Any question you might have about my answer you can ask them on comments there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already reduced the problem to proving that $\bigcap \limits_{n=1 } ^{\infty } \left(X \setminus E_n\right)=X\setminus \left(\bigcup \limits_{n=1 } ^{\infty } \left(E _n\right)\right)$.

Let $x\in X$. The following holds:

$$
\begin{align}
x\in \bigcap \limits_{n=1 } ^{\infty } \left(X \setminus E_n\right)&\iff \forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x\in X\setminus E_n\right)\\
&\iff \forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x\in X\land x\not \in E_n\right)\\
&\iff \forall n\in \mathbb N(x\in X)\land  \forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x\not \in E_n\right)\\
&\iff x\in X\land \forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x\not \in E_n\right)\\
&\iff x\in X\land \neg \exists n\in \mathbb N\left(x\in E_n\right)\\
&\iff x\in X\land x\not \in \left(\bigcup \limits_{n=1 } ^{\infty } \left(E _n\right)\right)\\
&\iff x\in X\setminus \left(\bigcup \limits_{n=1 } ^{\infty } \left(E _n\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/635373/55235) for the definition of limit of a sequence of sets being used here and a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks!, but how is it that $x \notin E _n $ is equivalent to $\forall n \in \mathbb N (x \notin E _n ) $

Comment: @Alexander I didn't write that. Which passage troubles you?

Comment: $\forall n \in \mathbb N (x \in X \wedge x \notin E _n ) \iff \forall n \in \mathbb N (x \in X ) \wedge  \forall n \in \mathbb N (x \notin E _n )$

Comment: That's just distributivity of the universal quantifier over the conjunction. It's a known logical property that $\forall y(P(y)\land Q(y))\iff \forall yP(y)\land \forall yQ(y)$. I tried to explain it in this comment, but the explanation was too long for this comment. I'll post one direction below.

Comment: Informally one can argue like this. $\boxed{\implies}$ Suppose $\forall n \in \mathbb N (x \in X \wedge x \notin E _n)$ is true. One wishes to check that $\forall n \in \mathbb N (x \in X ) \wedge  \forall n \in \mathbb N (x \notin E _n )$, so let's prove each part separately. Let $n\in \mathbb N$. By hypothesis one gets $x\in X\land x\not \in E_n$, in particular $x\in X$ follows. Therefore $\forall n\in\mathbb N(x\in X)$. Similarly $\forall n\in \mathbb N(x\not \in E_n)$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb N (x \in X ) \wedge  \forall n \in \mathbb N (x \notin E _n )$ follows.